# How to know that QDataStream cannot deserialize something?

Tags: c++, qt, deserialization, qdatastream

Please, consider the following code fragment from the [`QDataStream`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#details) documentation:

```
QFile file("file.dat");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QDataStream in(&file);    // read the data serialized from the file
QString str;
qint32 a;
in >> str >> a;           // extract "the answer is" and 42
```

Is there a way to know that `QDataStream` cannot deserialize the content of the file to `QString` and `qint32` and how to handle such deserialization errors in `QDatastream`?

Comment: I like to include a checksum of the data and check its validity before even attempting to deserialize. Passing that check dramatically increases the chances of successful deserialization. Just don't use Qt's own checksum function, which is fairly mediocre with its 16 bit output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to official documentation, you can (and should) use [Read Transactions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#details):

```
  in.startTransaction();

  QString str;
  qint32 a;

  in >> str >> a; // try to read packet atomically

  if(in.commitTransaction())
  {
      // read is ok, check the data you had read
  } 
  else
  {
      // wait for more data or show unknown error
  }
```

If you have a file as an IO device, you can read without transactions, but you have to check manually whether the necessary amount of data is available. When using QDataStream you shall be sure about a sequence and composition of data.

Comment: Could you please provide more code that shows how it helps to find if there is an error in incoming data. For example if file.dat was garbage.

Comment: Is it just:
    if (!in.commitTransaction()) {
        qDebug("eror");
    }

Comment: @uni , you have to check your data yourself. `QDataStream` is only responsible for the read operation itself if data available to read

Comment: What I meant is a way to check if incoming data at least can be extracted from datastream (An I will check it later). Your answer really helps. Thank you! Спасибо!